# Converting MySQL BIT field to BOOLEAN with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code.

Using Doctrine 2 with PHP 5.3 MySQL 5.5

My YAML mapping for a BIT field called IsDefault which has values of 1 or 0 depeding if I want the value to be true or false in my application:

```
  IsDefault:
    type: boolean
    nullable: false
```

The generated Entity is:

```
/**
* @var boolean $IsDefault
*/
private $IsDefault;


/**
 * Set IsDefault
 *
 * @param boolean $isDefault
 * @return Model
 */
public function setIsDefault($isDefault)
{
    $this->IsDefault = $isDefault;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get IsDefault
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getIsDefault()
{
    return $this->IsDefault;
}
```

Unfortunately when accessing the data in my app every row returns IsDefault as TRUE.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Dumb question, but does the underlying db actually contain records where the `IsDefault` column is `FALSE`?

Comment: is db stored value 0/1 or TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: @eggyal a good question actually ;-) I was assuming the OP was concerned about handling 0/1 vs. TRUE/FALSE in code, but then again, in PHP, the "type" system is loose to say the least

Comment: Shamefully I have solved this within 5 minutes of writing.. 

I have converted the db field type to TINYINT(1) rather than BIT. 

Thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and I change `Bit(1)` to `TINYINT(1)` and is working well.